# Search Filter using angular, How to use '| filter: 'some text' from controller

Tags: angularjs

What is wrong in this:

jsfiddle.net/TTY4L/3/

I am trying to make a filter kind of list, when i 
 
enter some value, say 'avi', it should list like

- Avi
- Ravi,

I know the logic to do So, {{['Avi','Ravi','Raj','Raghuram'] | filter:'avi'}}, But i could not able to get, how to put this in controller, and display from there, Can i use $filter for this, If yes, then how can i.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="searchItem in searchItems | filter:searchFilter">{{searchItem}}</li>
```

abd here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJeG3/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Actually i want to do it in controller itself, and fill the details from there, so that i can get a filtered array and do some logic in controller in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the filter into the controller like this.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter){

     $scope.names = $filter('filter')('searchText');
}
```

Comment: $filer('avi');, i think we cannot call like this, the above said thinks are correct, But i really thank you if you give a clear cut implementation of using  $filter('avi'); in this senerio, actually i want to do it in controller itself, and fill the details from there

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in your **ng-repeat**

```
<li ng-repeat="searchItem in searchItems|filter:searchFilter:strict">{{searchItem}}</li>
```